# What is Pep8 ErrorCode E41?

Tags: python, pep8

All the examples of using pep8 and flake8 use the following configuration setting:

```
[pep8]
ignore = E226,E302,E41
max-line-length = 160
```

The question I have is "What is E41"?

Does this ignore line somehow ignore E401 and E402?
This is the documentation for E4 errors:

```
E4  Import
E401    multiple imports on one line
E402    module level import not at top of file
```

Comment: I think this is a typo.

Comment: I can't find any justification in commit history, nor any kind of documentation for the error code, nor any point that would generate such an error code. All I can say is that it ignores all errors that _start with_ `E41` (which is none, as far as I can tell).

Comment: I'd take this question to the author(s)/maintainer(s) of the tool in question, maybe in the form of a bug report.

Comment: I did file an issue with the pep8 utility project. I think as other that this is likely a typo.

Answer (score 5):

From the first answer to [this issue](https://github.com/learningequality/kolibri/issues/3609):

> Note: E41 means that all E41* codes will be ignored, but since currently there are no E41* codes, that's a noop.